# how to search for an item in a list?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Here goes the fiddle for a serach field (this is just for reference) : https://jsfiddle.net/pvwvdgLn/1/

The deal is - the search box is used to search for an employee in the list of names in the leaderboard.(in reality the leaderboard contains 800 employees which is echoed from a database)

**Problem :** The searchbox doesnot work when I toggle to the overall LB and search for an employee.

**issue I suspect :**  same ol id = "myOL" for both list as onkeyup="myFunction()" call it.When I toggle the list,it should fetch data from the other id which I set for overall LB list.

I tried the above thing that I suspect.But messed up wiyh the JS.

**The search box works for "weekly Lb".**

**html code for search box :**

```html
<div id="search5back">

  <form method="get" action="/search" id="searchbox5">
  <input id="search52" name="q" type="text" size="40" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search an Employee ...." />
    </form>

  </div>
```

**code for the two lists in the leaderboard :- weekly Leaderbaord**

```html
 <div id="weeklylb" class="leadboardcontent">

   <div class="leaderboard" id="leaderboard">
   <ol id = "myOL">
   <li>
   <mark>
  <?php  while( $toprow4 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt4) ) {

  echo  "<div class='parent-div'><span class='rank'>" . $toprow4['rank'] . "</span><span class='name'>" . $toprow4['EmployeeName'] . "</span><span class='points'>" . $toprow4['pointsRewarded'] . "</span></div>";

  } ?>
   </mark>
   </li>
   </ol>
   </div>

     </div>
```

**code for the two lists in the leaderboard :- Overall Leaderbaord**

```html
  <div class="leaderboard" id="leaderboard">
  <ol id = "myOL">
  <li>
  <mark>
  <?php  while( $toprow2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt3) ) {

  echo  "<div class='parent-div'><span class='rank'>" . $toprow2['overallRank'] . "</span><span class='name'>" . $toprow2['EmployeeName'] . "</span><span class='points'>" . $toprow2['Total_points_Rewarded'] . "</span></div>";

  } ?>
  </mark>
  </li>
  </ol>
  </div>
```

**javascript related to the two tabs(weekly LB and Overall LB) :-**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.tab a').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var _this = $(this);
            var block = _this.attr('href');
            $(".tab").removeClass("active");
            _this.parent().addClass("active");
            $(".leadboardcontent").hide();
            $(block).fadeIn();
        });


        /**
         * Fade in the Popup
         */
        $('.leaderboard li').on('click', function () {
            $('#popup').fadeIn();
            var mark = $(this).find('name').text();
            var small = $(this).find('points').text();
            $('#popup-name').text('Name: ' + name);
            $('#popup-score').text('Score: ' + points);
        });

});
```

**js related to the search box :**

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, ol, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("search52");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ol = document.getElementById("myOL");
  li = ol.getElementsByTagName("li");
  divs=li[0].getElementsByClassName("parent-div");
  for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
      a = divs[i].getElementsByClassName("name")[0];
      if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          divs[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
          divs[i].style.display = "none";
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Search is working now

There were some errors in coding

- myFunction() should be out of $(document).ready(function(){}),this is jquery
- `divs=li[0].getElementsByClassName("parent-div");` is of no use.There is no class with this name.

So Finally JS

```
 function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, ol, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("search52");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ol = document.getElementById("myOL");
  li = ol.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("mark")[0];
    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tab a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var _this = $(this);
    var block = _this.attr('href');
    $(".tab").removeClass("active");
    _this.parent().addClass("active");
    $(".leadboardcontent").hide();
    $(block).fadeIn();
  });


  /**
   * Fade in the Popup
   */
  $('.leaderboard li').on('click', function() {
    $('#popup').fadeIn();
    var mark = $(this).find('mark').text();
    var small = $(this).find('small').text();
    $('#popup-name').text('Name: ' + mark);
    $('#popup-score').text('Score: ' + small);
  });
});
```

[Plunker Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/kDbap9IJkCJc0lfA3a2w?p=preview) For Demo.

Hope this helps.Thank you